# How to redirect wordpress post links that are using post_id to new url struture of postname

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a slight problem... we made a change to our url structure the other day and have broken links all over.

What I did was change links from:

http://blog.mydomain.com/articles/123

To:

http://blog.mydomain.com/articles/this-is-a-smaple

Is there anyway to direct any links linking to the pages ID number to the postname????

The old url structure is still being published throughout our RSS feed on facebook. So I am trying to catch those people that are or maybe clicking on our links on our facebook posts and redirect them to that posts postname url? Does that make sense?

Thanks and help would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew,

You can use the [Advanced Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) plugin. It'll redirect old permalink structures to the correct posts. Checkout the description on the plugin page.

Comment: I just tried this and the migration option did not work for me. I tested it by entering the old permalink structure and I kept getting this link is broken page.

Comment: I have on the other hand updates our 404 page and have given those looking for our published facebook posts extra info to find that particular post.

Answer (score 0):

In your new URL handling code, check to see if everything after the last slash is decimal numbers, if so, use the old URL handling code.

Comment: Well we made the change in order to better optimize our pages for SEO purposes.

So I guess there is no way of placing a htaccess file that would look for the old structure then re-direct to its equivalence in the postname url structure